# Getting variables from one class to another in java

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

I'm trying to get the variable `correct` which contains info from the method `actionPerformed` in the `Window` class to the method `paint` from the `Display` class. I can't figure out how to do it because the `Window` class also takes 3 int values when called.

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    /**
     * Constructor for Window
     */
    public Window(int width, int height, int gridSize)
    {
        //save instance variables:
        WIDTH = width;
        HEIGHT = height;
        this.gridSize = gridSize;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        int moveCode;
        int direction;
        Words guess = new Words();

        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("button"))  //button has been pressed
        {
            //get entered values from textfields:
            String num = numField.getText();
            String dir = ltrField.getText();
            String word = wordField.getText();
            String correct;

            //convert to number:
            int numberWord = Integer.parseInt(num) - 1;

            //convert "A" or "D" to 0 or 1:
            if(dir == "A")
            {
                direction = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                direction = 1;
            }

            if(guess.words[numberWord][direction].equals(word))
            {
                correct = word;
            }
            else
            {
                correct = "No";
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Display extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g); //clear the old drawings
        final int PAD = 20;      //extra space so field isn't right at edges
        if(correct == "Java")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am just guessing here, but 9/10 times a window object will be created in your super class (where you call paintComponent on). Get the window from there and add a getter method.

Answer (score 0):

`String correct;` variable is defined inside `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` which makes it *a local variable*. A local variables "lives" inside a method and is no available outside of that method. What you can do is to define `correct` as *an instance variable* at `Window` class level.

```
class Window {
    private String correct; 
    public String getCorrect() { 
        return correct;
    }
}
```

and later on you can use it inside `Display` class like this :

```
Window window = getWindow();
String correct = window.getCorrect();
```

Comment: It says that it "cannot find symbol - method getWindow()". Is this because I'm using BlueJ?

Comment: @HiMyNameIsW you will need to define such method. Or you can pass a window object as an additional parameter to public void paintComponent(Graphics g) method.

Comment: I tried this "Window window = new Window(25,25,25);" which I know doesn't work because it's already been made, but I can't figure out what else to do.